# Insert statement with high buffer gets and high index contention

Tags: performance, oracle

We have a table with over 300,000,000 rows and two single column indexes. Every now and then the application comes to a hault. At that same time there is high index contention for the insert statement for this table. I also noticed a large amount of buffer gets. Can someone help me remedy this problem?

Here are statistics for the statement when the index contention is high and we are having performance issues.

```
                     Total        Per Execution     Per Row
Executions          51,857        1                 1.00
Elapsed Time (sec)  3,270.67      0.06              0.06
CPU Time (sec)      1,554.41      0.03              0.03
Buffer Gets         140,844,228   2,716.01          2,716.01
Disk Reads          1,160         0.02              0.02
Direct Writes       0             0.00              0.00
Rows                51,857        1.00              1
Fetches             0             0.00              0.00
```

Same statement, same time range, similar workload.

```
                     Total        Per Execution     Per Row
Executions           94,424        1                1.00
Elapsed Time (sec)   30.41         <0.01            <0.01
CPU Time (sec)       12.90         <0.01            <0.01
Buffer Gets          1,130,297     11.97            11.97
Disk Reads           469           <0.01            <0.01
Direct Writes        0             0.00              0.00
Rows                 94,424        1.00             1
Fetches              0             0.00             0.00
```

Comment: Is one of the indexes a primary key based on a sequence?

Comment: Yes it is a sequence.

Comment: One of the possible scenario was described here:

http://sai-oracle.blogspot.ru/2009/04/beware-of-index-contention-after-mass.html   But not sure this is your case. Do you have ASSM tablespaces ?

Comment: do you have a cache on the sequence? (of a decent size, say at least 1000)

Comment: Segment Management = Auto

Comment: What are you seeing that leads you to believe that the problem is index contention (not that I disbelieve you, I'd just like to see exactly what the problem is).  Is this a RAC cluster?

Comment: this is not a cluster

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to look at a primary index:

1. a way to do fast lookups for the most common queries
2. a way to speed up insertions (and posibly deletions)

most people think in terms of the primary index in the first sense
but there can be only one primary key, since it actual disk order

By having a sequence (or a timestamp) as the primary key, you are basically trying to put records very close (same page) and can have contention, as all inserts try to go to the same place

If you use your primary key instead to distribute the data, you will have fewer insert collisions.  It can pay to have a primary key that is the most variable attribute (closest to a good distribution), even if that attribute is rarely queried, in fact adding an extra column with a random value can be used.

There is not enough information provided about how you use the data, but it might pay to trade a bit of query time, to avoid these collisions.